# Get the value of a variable during runtime (Console)

Tags: c#, input, console

I'm currently working on a hobby project involving a console application. In my program, I fetch data, transform it and eventually it gets parsed to `json`. The rough structure looks like this:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    var worker = new Worker();
    var start = DateTime.Now;
    var workSpeed = 0.0;
    Console.WriteLine($"Initialisation started at {start}");
    sw.Start();
    var materials = worker.GatherMaterials();
    var workStart = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine($"Work started at {workStart}.");
    var products = new List<Product>();
    foreach (var material in materials)
    {
        try
        {
            var product = worker.Process(material);
            products.Add(product);
            sw.Stop();
            workSpeed = (double)products.Count / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
            sw.Start();   
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            break;
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine();
    var finish = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine($"Work finished at {finish}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Ran from {start} to {finish} for approximately {sw.Elapsed} ms.");
    Console.WriteLine($"Processed {products.Count} products for an average processing speed of {workSpeed} products/s.");
    var jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions()
    {
        Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.All),
        WriteIndented = true
    };
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(products, jsonOptions);
    File.WriteAllText("products.json", json, Encoding.UTF8);
    Console.WriteLine("Saved all products to products.json");
}
```

There's a bit of code inside the `try` block where I temporarily stop the stopwatch to update the processing speed. I did this so that I could put a break point there to check the processing speed. However, I don't want to always run this application in debug mode. Ideally, I'd like to get rid of the part where I stop and resume the stopwatch and instead to have a way to interact with the variables directly through the console.

For example, would it be possible to have a persistent question in the terminal that says something like `Press S to get the current processing speed`, so that the value of the `workSpeed` variable shows up whenever I press S?

Comment: You can create another thread that waits for S to be pressed and using Console.ReadKey the writes the value of workSpeed.

Comment: Not sure who closed this question, but with two people mentioning working with different threads, I'm curious to see if anyone can provide an answer that would illustrate that approach.

Comment: In the first duplicate link it provides an example of using a separate thread

Comment: when I posted my comment yesterday, I didn't have time to post answer with code. Since the question is closed now, here is a [git gist](https://gist.github.com/sherif-elmetainy/96716c0b28f2ef1eab8a3c10f39c3dab) with code on how to do it with a thread.

Comment: Thanks @SherifElmetainy, I'll have a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the value of `Console.KeyAvailable` to see if the user pressed a key (it will be `true` if they did), and then use `Console.ReadKey(true)` to capture the key that they pressed (`true` means it won't be displayed).

For example:

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();

Console.WriteLine("Press 'S' to display the elapsed time, 'Q' to quit...");

sw.Start();

while (true)
{
    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

        if (input == ConsoleKey.S)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed time: {sw.Elapsed.ToString("c")}");
        }
        else if (input == ConsoleKey.Q)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine($"All done. Total elapsed time: {sw.Elapsed.ToString("c")}");
Console.Write("Press any key to exit...");
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Comment: So for my code, I would put the `KeyAvailable` logic inside my `foreach` loop, right?

Comment: @JansthcirlU Correct, along with the other code in your loop. This is just a few lines that check for user input, and if it's a value we care about, displays something to the console and then keep on loopin'

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll give that a shot if I have the chance. It could be a while before I can report on the results, just a heads up.

Comment: No hurry. Better to wait a while in case a better answer comes in anyway. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think the best alternative is to go for a multithreaded approach: keep your actual logic in a separate thread, and have the main thread handle the queries you're interested in. Note that with a multithreaded approach you will need to have shared resources between the 2 threads (and eventually do some synchronization), in order to get the rate you're interested in.

Comment: Can you provide a brief example?